# pyodbc session error when django project is downloaded from gitlab

Tags: django, gitlab, django-sessions, django-pyodbc

i have a django project which works fine when not uploaded
i have uploaded it to gitlab with following command:

```
1. git clone ssh://git@gitlab****dcms-api.git
2. git checkout dcms_sso
3.git add .
```

then i took the same code from git lab:

```
1. git clone ssh://git@gitlab****dcms-api.git
2. git checkout dcms_sso
```

just changed the application name in manifest file.
when i tried to run it throws following error:

```
File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
ERR     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 307, in get_new_connection
  ERR     timeout=timeout)
ERR pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
ERR The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
ERR Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
ERR     response = get_response(request)
ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
ERR     response = self.process_response(request, response)
ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 58, in process_response
ERR     request.session.save()
ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 81, in save
ERR     return self.create()
ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/1/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 51, in create
 ERR     self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()
```

please let me know if more log to be uploaded or if my backend.py should be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

error was with .profile file while uploading it to cloudfoundry. Worked after copying the .profile file